# AutoPostBack on ASP TextBox in UpdatePanel not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a TextBox control with a ColorPickerExtender on a form that sets a background color.  I'd like two things to happen when the user changes the color:

- The color of the control changes
- I get an immmediate AJAX event so I can make changes in other parts of the page

The color change is working fine with the `onColorChanged()` JavaScript.  My event handler also triggers both during a full postback and a partial/AJAX postback generated from other controls.  However, it does not generate an immediate postback itself.

Here are the relevant lines of the .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FingerTipDisplay.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditorLayoutv3.aspx.cs" Inherits="FingerTipDisplay.config.EditorLayoutv3" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxControlToolkit" %>



<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGeneralLayoutData" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Background color:" CssClass="ContentBodyText" ToolTip="Select the background color for this layout"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLayoutBackgroundColor" runat="server" ToolTip="Select the background color for this layout" CssClass="ColorPickerExtenderTextBox" Width="50" OnTextChanged="txtLayoutBackgroundColor_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxControlToolkit:ColorPickerExtender TargetControlID="txtLayoutBackgroundColor" runat="server"  OnClientColorSelectionChanged="onColorChanged" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the ScriptManager from the site master:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smFingerTipDisplay" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Here is the event handler:

```
protected void txtLayoutBackgroundColor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    moLayout.BackgroundColor = txtLayoutBackgroundColor.Text;

    if (moLayout.BackgroundColor.Substring(0, 1) != "#")
    {
        moLayout.BackgroundColor = "#" + moLayout.BackgroundColor;
    }

    // TODO: update preview image
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
onColorChanged = function (oSender) {
    /// <summary>Callback to use for when a color picker extender changes colors.  This
    /// sets the foreground and background of the TextBox control to the selected color.
    /// <param name='oSender' type='Object'>The control that changed</param>
    oSender.get_element().style.color = "#" + oSender.get_selectedColor();
    oSender.get_element().style.backgroundColor = "#" + oSender.get_selectedColor();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean 'immediate postback' ? Textbox fire postback after text was changed and exit (lost focus). Postback are not fired while typing inside textbox

Comment: Is this what is supposed to happen: the color picker selects a color, and assigns that color to the textbox, which triggers the TextChanged event on the server (within the updatepanel or as a trigger of another updatepanel, so it's async)?

Comment: funny.. the question title claims that UpdatePanel is not working... yet it is not present in your code. follow this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx and find the <Triggers> section sample.. that would help you observer how it should be done

Comment: @codefox, I mean after loss of focus.

Comment: @Brian, that's exactly what I want to happen.

Comment: @ymz, apologies if my question wasn't complete enough--I edited the snippet to show the UpdatePanel and ScriptManager...let me know if there's anything else needed.  I reviewed the link and didn't see anything that helped me.

Comment: Can you try to set `UpdateMode` to `Conditional` and set the `Triggers` to `TextBox TextChanged Event`? I am sure you need triggers for events other than Click of a button.

Comment: as i mentioned in my last post... and as **choz** just pointed out -  you MUST specify triggers if you wish that code to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.  It turns out that when the `ColorPickerExtender` changes the text in the corresponding `TextBox` it does not raise the `TextChanged` event at all.  Manually typing in the `TextBox` generated the desired effect, however, so I just added this to the `onColorChanged` handler:

```
oSender.get_element().onchange();
```

Now it works.  Thanks to all for your help.